# Very basic function in Bash showing returned value

Tags: bash, cgi

I have some questions about Bash, im used to modern languages and i need to develop some stuff in Bash but some things doesn't work as i want.

I have a function :

```
function is_directory
{
 if (test -d "$1"); then 
  return true
 fi
 return false
}
```

i call this function but i want to echo the result on a webpage, (im working with CGI) .. so how do i echo returned values?

```
echo is_directory "/home/pepe"
```

wont display true it will display " is_directory "/home/pepe" "  as a string itself u.u

and how do i display string returned values ??

Thanks!

Comment: try echo ``is_directory "/home/page"``

Comment: that's echo <backtick>is_directory "/home/page"<backtick>

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do it is to `echo` out the answer you want in the function itself like so:

```
is_directory()
{
  [[ -d "$1" ]] && echo true || echo false
}
```

#### Output

```
$ is_directory /etc
true

$ is_directory /foo
false
```

Answer (score 3):

Bash and other shells return an exit code as an int in the range 0-255. Using `return true` or `return false` always produces an error since `return` expects a numeric value. You can access the return value in the special variable `$?`.

```
$ foo () { return 42; }; foo; echo $?
42
```

Here are some ways to write your function:

Return a value:

```
is_directory () {
    test -d "$1"
}
```

To use it:

```
if is_directory "foo"    # note that there are no parentheses or brackets
then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

Output a string:

```
is_directory () {
    if [ -d "$1" ]
    then
        echo "true"
    else
        echo "false"
    fi
}
```

To use it:

```
if [[ $(is_directory "foo") == true ]]
then
    do_something
fi
```

Using this last version of the function, you can do the command that you show in your question like this:

```
echo "$(is_directory "/home/pepe")"
```

which will output "true" or "false" but the `echo` is unnecessary. This will do the same thing:

```
is_directory "/home/pepe"
```